# AS3: Why does datatype automatically change from TextField to DisplayObject on its own?

Tags: actionscript-3, casting, types, displayobject

What's happening in this simple piece of AS3 code? Why does my object change from TextField to the more generic DisplayObject?

```
public class Menu extends MovieClip
     {
      private var active_button:SimpleButton;

      public function Menu() 
      {
       active_button = SimpleButton( menu_list.getChildAt( 0 )); // ignore menu_list. it's just a collection of SimpleButtons
       trace( active_button.upState ); // [object TextField]
                // ** What's occuring here that makes active_button.upState no longer a TextField? **
       active_button.upState.textColor = 0x000000; // "1119: Access of possibly undefined property textColor through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject."
```

This question is simliar to [AS3: global var of type SimpleButton changes to DisplayObject for unknown reason, won't let me access .upState.textColor!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158886/as3-global-var-of-type-simplebutton-changes-to-displayobject-for-unknown-reason). I'm posting this because its more focused and deals with a single aspect of the broader issue.

Comment: To me these two questions look like a duplicate.  I'm not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the difference between compile time and run-time type.  In this code:

```
trace( active_button.upState ); // [object TextField]
```

You're passing the object to trace and trace is going to show the actual object type that exists at run-time.

However, in this case:

```
active_button.upState.textColor = 0x000000;
```

You're writing code that uses the object in `upState`.  upState is defined as `DisplayObject` and all `DisplayObject` don't have a `textColor` property, so it has to give you an error.  `upState` is allowed to actually contain anything that is a `DisplayObject` or a subclass of `DisplayObject` like a `TextField`.

You can tell the compiler that you know for sure it's a `TextField` by casting it.

```
TextField(active_button.upState).textColor = 0x000000;
```

There is another form of casting using the `as` keyword which will return the object, typed as specified, or `null`.  You want to use this keyword to test if an object is a certain type and then conditionally use it (via a `!= null` check).

```
var textField:TextField = active_button.upState as TextField;
if (textField != null) {
    textField.textColor = 0;
}
```